# Javascript Function is treating my string argument like an integer

Tags: javascript, object-type

I have a javascript function that contains an argument.

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeAvatar(0684839741);">Click here</a>
```

I need that argument to be a string because sometimes there will be Letters or a Leading 0 that I will need to preserve like in this example.

I checked to make sure that the argument that is passed in is a string with

```
x.constructor === String
```

But in my changeAvatar function, the argument comes through as no longer a string.  Instead it is a  number and removes the leading zero or breaks if it contains a letter.

How do I get the argument to retain it's type?

Comment: Have you tried adding single quote marks (apostrophes) around your argument?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've typed it as a javascript number as this line of javascript evaluates it to a number:

```
changeAvatar(0684839741);
```

If you want it to be a string, you have to do it this way where you explicitly declare it as a string like:

```
changeAvatar('0684839741');
```

which means the whole line should be this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeAvatar('0684839741');">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add single quotes:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeAvatar('0684839741');">Click here</a>
```