# Javascript - Pass number with zero to function

Tags: javascript, numbers, alert, zero

I'm trying to pass a number with zeroes (cuz is form database) to a javascript function:

```
<table>

   <tr onClick="View(<?php echo $id; ?>)">
      <td> <?php echo $id; ?> </td>
   </tr>

</table>
```

Javascript function:

```
   function View(id){
    alert(id);
   }
```

For exm.: 
If my id is `0005`, alert `5`.
If my id is `0006`, alert `6`.

I need to alert '`0005`' - '`0006`' but i can't solve this.

Thank you for answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Function is treating my string argument like an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583636/javascript-function-is-treating-my-string-argument-like-an-integer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
onClick="View(<?php echo $id; ?>)"
```

to

```
onClick="View('<?php echo $id; ?>')"
```

JavaScript is interpreting the value as a number so you need to tell it to use the value as a string by enclosing it in quotes.